# stop-computer : Privilege not held

Tags: windows-7, powershell-4.0

I am running Powershell (v4) on a Windows7 box ; I was able to until yesterday (2017-04-12) to issue a 'stop-computer' command to shutdown my computer.

Today: I am unable to do so; I get this response: ('zaphod' is the hostname):

```
 PS C:\Windows\system32> stop-computer
 stop-computer : Privilege not held.
 At line:1 char:1
 + stop-computer
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (zaphod:String) [Stop-Computer], ManagementException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StopComputerException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopComputerCommand
```

This happens when I start Powershell with non-admin permissions; or if I use 'Run as Administrator' (and it is running as Administator ; since I get the "User Account Control' popup when I do this).

There were some automatic Windows Updates made to my machine today - maybe these are somehow responsible ?

Oddly; 'restart-computer' *does* work.

Is this a known thing ? Can I get my permissions back somehow ?

**More research follows:**

**EDIT**: if I issue the command with the '-asjob' flag - it *does* work:

```
stop-computer -asjob # this works !
```

I issued the following command to get help:

```
get-help Stop-Computer -full
```

The 'Authentication' Flag is defined as follows:

```
Authentication <AuthenticationLevel>
   Specifies the authentication level that is used for the  WMI connection. (Stop-Computer uses WMI.) The default
   value is Packet.

   Valid values are:

   Unchanged:       The authentication level is the same as the previous command.
   Default:         Windows Authentication.
   None:            No COM authentication.
   Connect:         Connect-level COM authentication.
   Call:            Call-level COM authentication.
   Packet:          Packet-level COM authentication.
   PacketIntegrity: Packet Integrity-level COM authentication.
   PacketPrivacy:   Packet Privacy-level COM authentication.
   [...]
```

So confusingly the 'default' Authentication is apparently 'Packet'; but the flag to switch to 'Windows Authentication' is called 'Default'.

In any case; none of the flags allow me to shutdown the computer.
I get a slight variation of the error when I use "None":

```
stop-computer : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:1 char:1
+ stop-computer -Authentication None
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-Computer], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopComputerCommand
```

I also switched on tracing using:

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 2
```

Now I get this ; but I don't know what to make of it:

```
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> stop-computer
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
DEBUG:   19+                                         if ( &  >>>> { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $_.PSMessageDetails } )
{
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
DEBUG:   19+                                         if ( & {  >>>> Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $_.PSMessageDetails } )
{
DEBUG:   19+                                         if ( & { Set-StrictMode -Version 1;  >>>> $_.PSMessageDetails } )
{
DEBUG:    1+ &  >>>> { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $this.Exception.InnerException.PSMessageDetails }
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
DEBUG:    1+ & {  >>>> Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $this.Exception.InnerException.PSMessageDetails }
DEBUG:    1+ & { Set-StrictMode -Version 1;  >>>> $this.Exception.InnerException.PSMessageDetails }
DEBUG:    1+ & { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $this.Exception.InnerException.PSMessageDetails  >>>> }
DEBUG:   19+                                         if ( & { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $_.PSMessageDetails  >>>> } )
{
DEBUG:   26+                                         $errorCategoryMsg = &  >>>> { Set-StrictMode -Version 1;
$_.ErrorCategory_Message }
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
DEBUG:   26+                                         $errorCategoryMsg = & {  >>>> Set-StrictMode -Version 1;
$_.ErrorCategory_Message }
DEBUG:   26+                                         $errorCategoryMsg = & { Set-StrictMode -Version 1;  >>>>
$_.ErrorCategory_Message }
DEBUG:   26+                                         $errorCategoryMsg = & { Set-StrictMode -Version 1;
$_.ErrorCategory_Message  >>>> }
DEBUG:   42+                                         $originInfo = &  >>>> { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $_.OriginInfo }
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'
DEBUG:   42+                                         $originInfo = & {  >>>> Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $_.OriginInfo }
DEBUG:   42+                                         $originInfo = & { Set-StrictMode -Version 1;  >>>> $_.OriginInfo }
DEBUG:   42+                                         $originInfo = & { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $_.OriginInfo  >>>> }
stop-computer : Privilege not held.
```

Comment: Can you shut down the computer from the same PowerShell prompt using `shutdown.exe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody from Microsoft posted on the [Powershell Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/65250s/windows_10_creators_update_stopcomputer_not/dgfofug/?st=j1o3oa29&sh=e0c29c6d) about this.

He explains that it is probably a regression bug from the [Security and Quality Rollup for the .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.6.1 patch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4014551/description-of-the-security-and-quality-rollup-for-the-net-framework-4).

You've already found the suggested workaround to use `-asjob`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, according to [“Privilege not held” error with PowerShell “stop-computer” command: Workaround after April 2017 security updates from CVE-2017-0160](http://%E2%80%9CPrivilege%20not%20held%E2%80%9D%20error%20with%20PowerShell%20%E2%80%9Cstop-computer%E2%80%9D%20command:%20Workaround%20after%20April%202017%20security%20updates%20from%20CVE-2017-0160)

Just install the update required for your OS version.

Comment: Link only answer for real, say what? Manu, c'mon Manu, for real!!